# Intellij markdown line wrap adding space

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

Please see the below images.

The first image shows the issue at hand; When writing a markdown file with the markdown plugin in intellij, the line wrapping adds a space at the beginning of the next line, and it accumulates for each new line. The bottom three images shows what I believe are the relevant settings.

Any idea why these extra spaces are being added? Is it a bug or a problem with my settings? It is really annoying having to always go back and delete the extra spaces.

[image: Illustrates the issue with spaces being added when line wrapping]

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the bug: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220392

You can disable hard wrap for Markdown (**Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Markdown > Wrap on typing**) and use only soft wrap (**Preferences | Editor | General > Soft Wraps**)

Comment: Is it possible to set softwrap margin? It seems like it only applies to the boundaries of the IDE